# PyCharm stopped to open files in the project

Tags: pycharm

Once large image file was created in project directory and I tried to open it. A special window appeared to ask to increase heap size or virtual memory (I don't remember).

And it's it: PyCharm is unable to open any file in the project anymore.

Deletion of that big image didn't helped.

If file clicked, it appears in breadcrumb, but no window shows.

How to reset incorrect project setup I probably made in increase heap dialog?

Comment: Have you tried `Settings | Invalidate Caches / Restart`?

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the .idea folder and recreate your PyCharm workspace.